# Office 365 Developer program E3 to E5

Tags: office365

I would love to know if there is any option to enable E5 instead of E3 on O365 Dev program.
As we are working on some showcases on Microsoft ground and developing into the environment, we could use some of the additional features of E5.

I just found this [link](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/blogs/new-microsoft-365-e5-subscription-with-ems-now-available-for-developers/) saying MS will announce once there is a way to "migrate". We have a lot of stuff configured across the tenant including SP sites, content as messages, plans and whatsoever so we definitely do not want to create a new environment.

Thanks for your answer.
Marek Kyzivat

Answer (score 0):

We've come to the same situation. Since Microsoft Offfice is providing Developer Trial E5 instead of E3. We are now using Trial E3 and want an upgrade/switch.

Comment: I've just opened a ticket from within the DEV tenant, will let you know what they respond.

Comment: Basically they told me to contact support here lol (via other channels...) can't seem to find anyone who could put me on right direction.

Comment: How can I migrate from an Office 365 E3 subscription to a Microsoft 365 E5 subscription?
Currently, only new Office 365 Developer Program members will get a Microsoft 365 E5 Developer subscription automatically. Existing users will be offered a way to migrate to a Microsoft 365 E5 subscription in the future. Rest assured, we are working to enable all Office 365 Developer Program members to migrate to Microsoft 365 E5.  from: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/developer-program/office-365-developer-program-faq